# Post image to facebook via python and graphapi

Tags: python, image, facebook-graph-api

Hoping to get some help with error I am getting.  I am able to authenticate and post text to a users wall (so I am thinking that I am properly authenticated).

The code I am using is as follows:

```
self.client = GraphAPI(ACCESS_TOKEN)
self.client.put_photo(open("test.jpg"), "test post from app - please ignore")
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\Projects\python Code\pyhton test programs\upload posts to facebook v3.py", line 69, in OnFacebookPublishButton
    self.client.put_photo(open("test.jpg"), "test post from app - please ignore")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facebook.py", line 231, in put_photo
    raise GraphAPIError(response)
facebook.GraphAPIError: Your photos couldn't be uploaded. Photos should be saved as JPG, PNG, GIF, BMP or TIFF files.
```

I have verified using the windows explore, ACDSee, Photoshop, Paint and Faststone, that the jpg are valid.

Comment: @shaktimaan thanks for the edit, I saw the typo after I posted and was trying to fix and couldn't because you had beat me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.client = GraphAPI(ACCESS_TOKEN)
with open("test.jpg","rb") as image:
    self.client.put_photo(image, "test post from app - please ignore")
```

the open function takes several parameters one of which is the mode in which it will open, your error is most likely that you did not specify the open mode after the file name.

Another important thing is that when you open a file, you also need to close it, so your code falters in the fact that it doesn't seem to include a .close() function call.

In my suggestion I open the image as read (binary) mode and use the with statement to avoid the closing statement.

I suggest you take some time to learn about the open function by reading the official docs
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Thank you, you solved it for me.  I had tried variations that included close but it was clear that was not the cause of the error, so I had not included those lines of code in my post.  It had however not occurred to me to set the filemode because none of the supposedly working examples that I found incorporated it.  Thanks again!!